# Confirm Delete Javascript message not getting displayed on 'IE11' and 'Chrome'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have confirm delete message in my application and it works on IE8-9 but not on 'IE11' and 'Chrome'. I checked all settings and scripts are enabled on both browsers.

When I click on 'delete' link nothing happens page is just refreshed and no message is displayed and record is not deleted.

This is my _delete_from_page.rhtml file in 'views' directory.

```
<%= render :partial => "layouts/top_menu"%>
<%= render :active_scaffold => "testing_page_chain"%>
<html>
  <head>
      <script language="javascript">
      function doRedirect()
      {
      var confirm_msg=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the request with ID <%=@d.controller_id%>?" ,"");
      var id=<%=@d.id%>
      if (confirm_msg==true)
        {
        window.location="<%= url_for(:controller => "#{params[:controller]}")%>/confirm_delete?id="+id;
        }
      else
        {
        window.location="<%= url_for(:controller => "#{params[:controller]}")%>/cancel_delete";
        }
      }

  function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
      window.onload = func;
    } else {
      window.onload = function() {
        if (oldonload) {
          oldonload();
        }
        func();
      }
    }
  }
</script>
  </head>
</html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=addLoadEvent(doRedirect)
</script>
```

and I call this from controller 'testing_page_chain_controller.rb' like

```
render :partial => "delete_from_page"
```

Comment: At 1st glance you miss semicolon after var id=<%=@d.id%>

Comment: You onload procedure looks prity complicated. Why dont you just have  window.onload=function(){doRedirect()};

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use data-confirm?

```
<%=link_to 'Delete', url, date: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

This is in Rails default installation by default. Then you can do your server stuff after they confirm they want to delete the object.

Comment: I have custom function 'confirm_delete' which gets called after 'confirm_msg==true', in that function I delete that record and it's entries from multiple tables. In your above suggestion how will you achieve custom function?